# How to read classes matching class name pattern (with or without extcos)?

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I want to do classpath scanning using some existing library. `extcos` seems to be a good candidate, because it supports JBoss's VFS out of the box.

Is it possible to run `extcos` (or some other classpath scanning tool), to that

- FS-based, JAR-based and JBoss's VFS's based classpaths are supported
- and only classes matching specific pattern (like `com.example.*.entity`) are loaded?

The first prerequisite seems to be already satisfied by `extcos`, but i'm unable to get the second one. It may happen that i have some weird classes in `com.example` package and i don't want to load them, not even try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Spring's application context class path scanning (i.e. resource loading) capabilities. This handles at least FS (file system) and Jar based class paths out of the box.

When on JBoss 5+, i use [Snowdrop](http://www.jboss.org/snowdrop)'s application context implementation that adds VFS support transparently for the application.

Since i'm using resource loading by pattern, i get package filtering, and even class name filtering for free.

Answer (score 1):

As for extcos (Extensible Component Scanner, http://extcos.sf.net): The first is supported as you rightly mention, but the second isn't currently possible. It's however a good idea, so I'll consider this as a feature to be added.

Comment: This will be better as an answer if the idea became implemented :) Until that extcos yielded poor performance in my (very preliminary) tests -- probably because i had plenty of jars full of classes on my classpath.

Comment: I'm happy to be able to tell you that version 0.4b of extcos has just been released. This new version actually includes support for wildcards in package names. Please see the [new user manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/extcos/files/releases/0.4b/extcos-0.4b-userManual.pdf/download) for more detailed information.